# Sticky Navbar Disapears When I Click On Hamburger in Mobile View Only

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, sticky

Not Sure why but the sticky navbar works fine except when I scroll down in mobile view. When I click on "Menu Click Here" the entire navbar disapears.

I think the javascript function is removing the sticky class but im not sure how to fix this.

http://lonestarwebandgraphics.com/

```
/* Toggle between adding and removing the "responsive" class to bottomnav when the user clicks on the icon */
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("mybottomnav");
if (x.className === "bottomnav") {
x.className += " responsive";
} else {
x.className = "bottomnav";
}
}
```

[image: Look at the sticky class Before I click]

[image: Sticky Class Disappears after I click on the "menu click here"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `myFunction` function.

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><p>Menu Click Here </p>  ☰</a>
```

Here, you call your `myFunction()` to toggle the state of the hamburger menu. However, the `myFunction` fails to manage the toggling.

So, for it to work, change your current version

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mybottomnav");
  if (x.className === "bottomnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "bottomnav";
  }
}
```

to this one below:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mybottomnav");
  if(x.classList.contains("responsive")) {
    x.classList.remove("responsive");
  } else {
    x.classList.add("responsive");
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh this definately make sense. Thank you I will try this after work.